# Proper Usage of Num Lock

Tags: shortcut-keys, numlock

I come from windows, and there I had the habbit of selecting the entire line by using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>. Now, when I press this combinations, I get just a <kbd>7</kbd>. No matter which is the state of the <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> key.

So, my question is: how can I select the entire line of text, by using keyboard shortcuts? How can I fix this problem. I don't need the 7 character to appear, when I press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>

PS: when NumLock is `ON` I get the numbers from the keys. When NumLock is `OFF` it moves the cursor as expected. The problem is that if I press Shift + NumLock Key I get the number.

I need to select the text while I keep shift pressed.

Comment: The same shortcut used in Ubuntu too.

Comment: @Perumal93: As I said, when I press the combination, I get the 7 character. How can I fix that?

Comment: Is your Num lock is ON?

Comment: @Perumal93 yes, check the PS section of the question. TY

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the steps:

1. Open up Terminal
2. Type `sudo gedit /etc/default/keyboard`
3. Modify `XKBOPTIONS=""` to `XKBOPTIONS="numpad:microsoft"`
4. Save and exit the editor
5. Reboot the system to take the changes in effect.

I hope the issue will now be solved.